# Python script to send and click link sent as notification

Tags: python, notification, libnotify

I'm writing a python script for linux that sends a notification to the notification bubble using **libnotify**. My issue is I'm sending a link as the notification and I want to be able to click that link when the notification appears. Upon clicking the link it should open a web browser displaying the contents of the link

Comment: Under Unity, notifications are explicitly forbidden to do this. Interaction is for dialog boxes and indicators, not notifications. Other Desktop Environments have different guidelines. Please edit your question to explain which Desktop Environments you intend this tool to be used in.

Comment: I think I found a work around it for both unity and gnome based environments. However thanks for your insight. I never knew about that til you pointed it out

Comment: @Atia Why not post your solution for people who come across this same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that using  Notify which comes with python **gi.repository** was way better than using libnotify. Because with Notify no extra work had to be done to make the links clickable plus it was easy to use.
It also worked when I tried it on ubuntu 16.04 which is a unity environment. Information about gi.repository and its many functionalities can be found here http://nullege.com/codes/search/gi.repository.Notify.Notification.new